# Is it possible to have a mysql table refer to a table in a foreign database?

Tags: mysql4

Is it possible to use a mysql table transparently though the table is an alias for a table in a foreign database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard doesn't support it, neither implementation of mysql db.